# paramiko: NameError: global name 'descriptor' is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssh

I'm trying to use `paramiko` for SSH, but got an error:

```
>>> import paramiko
>>> ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
>>> ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
>>> ssh.connect('54.***.***.110', key_filename='D:\Keys\MyOWN\priv.ppk')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\paramiko\client.py", line 366, in connect
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\paramiko\client.py", line 515, in _auth
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\paramiko\agent.py", line 343, in __init__
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\paramiko\agent.py", line 66, in _connect
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\paramiko\agent.py", line 83, in _send_message
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\paramiko\win_pageant.py", line 123, in send
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\paramiko\win_pageant.py", line 89, in _query_pageant
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\paramiko\_winapi.py", line 273, in get_security_attributes_for_user
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\paramiko\_winapi.py", line 222, in descriptor
NameError: global name 'descriptor' is not defined
```

Regarding [this issue](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/461) - it was solved, but - I still have this error (latest `paramiko` version, downloaded from it's Github).

May be - there is some other libs, to wok via SSH with RSA-key authorization? 
Or - any way to solve this `NameError`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like the issue is not really solved (I too downloaded latest zip: it can also be seen on [[GitHub]: paramiko/paramiko - (v1.15.2) paramiko/paramiko/_winapi.py](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/v1.15.2/paramiko/_winapi.py)), so you'll have to fix it yourself in your *paramiko* installation files (fixed in *v1.15.**3***):

- Edit your *${PYTHON_DIR}\build\bdist.win32\egg\paramiko\_winapi.py* (*${PYTHON_DIR}* is just a placeholder for your *Python* installation directory),
  and at lines *222* and *223* simply replace `descriptor` by `value`:

  ```
  self._descriptor = descriptor
  self.lpSecurityDescriptor = ctypes.addressof(descriptor)
  ```

  should become:

  ```
  self._descriptor = value
  self.lpSecurityDescriptor = ctypes.addressof(value)
  ```

Comment: Looks correct, but after I changed it to `self._descriptor = value` - still have same error - `NameError: global name 'descriptor' is not defined`; although - I re-installed `paramico` and restared my Python interpreter; may be I miss something?

Comment: I said that you also need to modify the next line (_223_): `self.lpSecurityDescriptor = ctypes.addressof(value)`. (do not touch the spaces at the begining of the lines).

Comment: OMG! Sorry :-) did not pay attention on next line :-)

Answer (score 1):

I used to get this type of errors. I restarted the machine and it got solved!

But I think there is a bug in the paramiko library. 
Changing `descriptor` by `value` as explained by *CristiFati* works fine.

Comment: Restarting the machine worked for me also! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I met the issue too, please try to set the `allow_agent=False`, and it should be resolved.

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('54.***.***.110', key_filename='D:\Keys\MyOWN\priv.ppk', allow_agent=False)
```